# Script to automatically replace icons by a specific .jpg

Tags: macos, icons, embedding, apple-music

Dear Stack overflow community,

I hope you are all doing good, before asking my request, I would like to point out that my coding skills are close to 0 but I can follow detailed protocols ;)

I have been trying to resolve my issue(s) using ChatGPT but I could not make it work.

**Here is what I want to achieve:**

I am a music nerd and I like to have my music collection well organized.
So far I have been doing the work manually but it is taking me way too long and I want to optimize the process.
Usually, for a given album I download the cover 600x600 using this website: https://bendodson.com/projects/itunes-artwork-finder/

Then I embed the cover to my music files using iTunes and replace the folder Icon by the downloaded .jpg using a simple copy paste

I recently found a script that allows me to automatically download and embed the cover to my music files (https://github.com/regosen/get_cover_art)
This is working quite good so far, it does what I want.

Now I would like to go to the next step and use the downloaded .jpg and automatically put it at the place of the folder icon.

Using the get_cover_art script I can have every Cover having the same name, by consequence I am looking for a script that scans folders and everytime it sees a Cover.jpg and take the picture to replace the folder icon.

Utimately having a script doing both one after the other would be AMAZING.

Is my request clear? Do you guys think it is feasible?
Thanks a lot for your help.

Best

I tried several scripts using ChatGPT but I got no results or I have a lot of python puglins missing...
Maybe they are easier ways.